# What was the last move made in this game?

Tags: chess, board-games, retrograde-analysis

What was white's last move in the game shown below?

[image]

**Note:** This is a screenshot taken from an actual game and all moves made were legal.

**ETA:** The last move played by white was the last move of the game which ended in a checkmate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you playing

> [bughouse chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bughouse_chess)?

If so,

> White's last move was to drop the rook, which their teammate (playing with the black pieces on the other board) captured, on h7.

Comment: Yes, this is the only possibility. The game must have been rot13(ohtubhfr be [penmlubhfr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazyhouse)). In this specific case, it was rot13(penmlubhfr, gur gjb cynlre inevnag).

Answer (score 3):

Of course it could also be

> another chess variant where the king is non-royal piece (i.e. it can be captured just like all other pieces), like Antichess (although I believe it's probably impossible in regular antichess with mandatory piece captures).

P.S.

> That means that the question (at least its title) is a bit incorrect, since a chess variant game (at least one using significantly different rules, like crazyhouse/bughouse) couldn't be called a *chess* game anymore.

Comment: If I had said rot13("purff inevnag") in the title it would have given away the trick. You are correct that it could have been rot13(Nagvpurff naq juvgr pbhyq unir cynlrq okt8 gb trg gur obneq vagb guvf cbfvgvba. Oynpx jbhyq abg unir arrqrq gb pncgher gur ebbx ba u7 fvapr gurl pbhyq unir znqr n pncgher ba nabgure cneg bs gur obneq.)

Comment: I have updated the question to address these issues. Thanks for pointing them out!

Answer (score 2):

The last move:

> The Rook moved from B7 to B8

Because:

> If the bishop was moved their would have already been a checkmate before by the two rooks. No other pieces could have been moved

Comment: Black is in check by the rook on h7, so this could not have happened by white moving to b8.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> 1. Rh7+ Bg7

Comment: Bg7 wouldn't be legal in that case...

Comment: Bg7 would not stop black from being in check.